# How can I take all targets' metrics in one page at Prometheus

Tags: devops, prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

I have Prometheus setup on AWS EC2. I have 11 targets configured which have 2+ endpoints. I would like to setup a endpoint/query etc to gather all the metrics in one page. I am pretty stuck right now. I could use some help thanks:)

[my prometheus targets file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdZHT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Prometheus adds an unique `instance` label per each scraped target according to [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/).
2. Prometheus provides an ability to select time series matching the given [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). For example, the following series selector selects time series containing `{instance="1.2.3.4:56"}` label, e.g. all the time series obtained from the target with the given `instance` label.
3. Prometheus provides the [/api/v1/series](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#finding-series-by-label-matchers) endpoint, which returns time series matching the provided `match[]` series selector.

So, if you need obtaining all the time series from a particular target `my-target`, you can issue the following request to `/api/v1/series`:

```
curl 'http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/series?match[]={instance="my-target"}'
```

If you need obtaining metrics from the `my-target` at the given timestamp, then issue the query with the series selector to [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries):

```
curl 'http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/query?query={instance="my-target"}&time=needed-timestamp'
```

If you need obtaining all the raw samples from the `my-target` on the given time range `(end_timestamp+d ... end_timestamp]`, then use the following query:

```
curl 'http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/query?query={instance="my-target"}[d]&time=end_timestamp'
```

See [these docs](https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639) for details on how to read raw samples from Prometheus.

If you need obtaining all the metrics / series from all the targets, then just use the following series selector: `{__name__!=""}`

See also [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) - this endpoint is used by Grafana for building graphs from Prometheus data.